# Changing directory for User in Ruby script

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I'm quite familiar with Dir.chdir("/xyz")

Unfortunately, this changes the directory of the process, but not actually the directory of the user.  I'll make the following example to illustrate my need.

```
$~/: ruby my_script.rb
CHANGING TO PATH FOR USER NOT SCRIPT

$/Projects/Important/Path: pwd
$/Projects/Important/Path
```

See?  I need the script to change the user's path.  Performing system/backticks/Dir.chdir all adjust the process path, and end with the user sitting where they started, instead of the path I want them.

From what I've read `exec` was the way to go, since it takes over the existing process... but to no avail.

Comment: You don't. Your shell won't let subprocesses it invokes change it's state, generally.

Comment: You cannot even do what you are trying to do running a shell script. The only way of doing something similar is “sourcing” the script, which doesn’t create a subshell, but you can not “source” a Ruby script (or make a Ruby script source something in the outer subshell).

Comment: I've read up on `exec` but it's not working as promised.

Comment: You could editor or create a .profile or othe shell config file, but it won't affect the current process.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can do something which might be good enough. You can invoke another shell from ruby:

```
Dir.chdir("/xyz")
system("bash")
```

Running this will create a **new** bash process, which will start in the `/xyz` directory. The downside is that changing this process will bring you back to the ruby script, and assuming it ends right away - back to the bash process that started the ruby script.

Comment: opening another shell is not the answer for me, sorry.  With the # of times this would be called, the user would be buried so deep in child shells, it would prove useless.

Comment: Do you really need it to be a ruby script? Have you considered using a bash function instead?

Answer (score 0):

Another hack that might work is to use [the prompt](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) as a hackish hook that will be called after each command. In the ruby script, you can write the new directory's path somewhere that can be read from both bash and ruby(for example a file - but **not** an environment variable!). In the `PROMPT_COMMAND` function, you check that file and `cd` to what's written there. Just make sure you delete that file, so you don't get automatically `cd`ed there after every command you run.

Comment: this won't work.  For instance I"m using zsh which has no PROMPT_COMMAND.  It's always sad when you find programming limitation, especially after spending time working towards a project that you'd think should have no barriers like this.